# List Comprehension Invalid Syntax error

Tags: python, list-comprehension

```
train_output = [x=1 if x>0 else x=-1 for x in train_output]
```

I keep gettting this syntax error:

```
File "<ipython-input-21-8f3b603b05fb>", line 9
    train_output = [x=1 if x>0 else x=-1 for x in train_output]
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you trying to put assignments in your list comprehension?

Comment: I want every value greater than zero to get the value 1 and every value less than zero to get the value negative 1. Did that answer your question?

Comment: `[1 if x>0 else -1 for x in train_output]` -- no need for assignements (which are illegal there, hence the syntax error).

Answer (score 3):

You have assignment statements, namely `x=1` and `x=-1`, within your assignment of `train_output`. Python is confused because it is trying to make the elements of the list `train_output` and you are interrupting it with calls to set x equal to 1.

I think what you are trying to accomplish is this

```
train_output = [1 if x>0 else -1 for x in train_output]
```